# How to get all element's inside particular ref in React.js , but in jquery way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

Below is my html structure.

```
<form className = "popupBody" ref = "popupBody" >
    <input/>  
    <input/>
</form>
```

Suppose I want all the inputs inside popupBody class and i want to clear its values , I will do that in jquery in below way .

```
 $('.popupBody input').val('');
```

But , I want to do same thing in React but using Refs. 
Like check the below code.

```
 $(this.refs.popupBody input).val('');
```

I am getting error for this.Is there any way to do this in react way using refs ?

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: Probably not strictly to the question, but you might want to get rid of jQuery at all. React [has](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) all you need to access and modify the input value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting an error because you are mixing an **object** and a **selector** in your `$()` call and that's not a valid [argument](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-selector-context).

You can keep using refs and jQuery for that, but you have to use `find()`

```
$(this.refs.popupBody input).val('');
```

should be

```
$(this.refs.popupBody).find('input').val('')
```

If you wanted to get all children, it would be something like this

```
$(this.refs.popupBody).children()
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/47458/)